# Python multiple search in arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

`idtopick` is an array of ids

```
     idtopick=array([50,48,12,125,3458,155,299,6,7,84,58,63,0,8,-1])
```

`idtolook` is another array containing the ids I'm interested in

```
     idtolook=array([0,8,12,50])
```

I would like to store in another array the positions of `idtopick` that corresponds to `idtolook`.

This is my solution

```
    positions=array([where(idtopick==dummy)[0][0] for dummy in idtolook])
```

Resulting in

```
    array([12, 13,  2,  0])
```

It works but in reality the arrays I'm working with store millions of point so the above script is rather slow. I would like to know if there's a way to make it faster. Also, I want to keep the order of `idtolook` so any algorithm that would sort it wouldn't work for my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sorting:

```
 sorter = np.argsort(idtopick, kind='mergesort') # you need stable sorting
 sorted_ids = idtopick[sorter]
 positions = np.searchsorted(sorted_ids, idtolook)
 positions = sorter[positions]
```

Note that it won't throw an error though if there is and `idtolook` missing in `idtopick`. You could actually sort idtolook into the results array too, which should be faster:

```
 c = np.concatenate((idtopick, idtolook))
 sorter = np.argsort(c, kind='mergesort')
 #reverse = np.argsort(sorter) # The next two lines are this, but faster:
 reverse = np.empty_like(sorter)
 reverse[sorter] = np.arange(len(sorter))
 positions = sorter[reverse[-len(idtolook):]-1]
```

Which has similarity to the set operations.